# Limit distribution of gaussian norm and Paley-Zygmund inequality (solution verification)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_i \sim \mathcal N(0, I_{d(n)})$ be iid normal random vectors taking values in $\mathbb R^{d(n)}$ where ${d(n)}$ is a sequence (dependent on a positive integer $n$) that grows such that ${d(n)}/n \rightarrow \gamma >0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for some positive constant $\gamma \in (0,1)$. Consider the following quantity:

$$Y_n = \left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \sum_i^n X_i\right \|_2^2$$

Does $Y_n$ have a limiting distribution? If so, what is it?

**What I've tried**

Rewriting, we have:

$$Y_n = \left\|\sqrt n\,\frac{1}{n} \sum_i^n X_i\right \|_2^2 = \left\|\sqrt n\, \bar X\right \|_2^2$$

where $\bar X \sim \mathcal N\left(0, I_{d(n)}/n\right)$ so that $Y_n$ is clearly chi squared distributed with $d(n)$ degrees of freedom. The chi squared distribution does not have a limiting distribution as the number of degrees of freedom increases to $\infty$. This shows that $Y_n$ does not converge in distribution.

The homework problem suggests to apply the [Paley-Zygmund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality) inequality, but I don't understand where that might be relevant. Any hints would be appreciated.

Paley-Zygmund:

$$\mathbb P[X\ge\theta \mathbb EX]\ge (1-\theta)^2\frac{\mathbb E[X]^2}{\mathbb E[X^2]}$$

Comment: Hint: Have you computed the mean and variance of $Y_n$ and then plug into the bound?

Comment: @E-A $P(Y_n \geq \theta d) \geq d^2/(2d+d^2) \rightarrow 0$ but I don't see how this lower bound tells me anything about the convergence in distribution.

Comment: That limit -assuming your expression is right- is 1/2, not 1? The point is that you can show that this violates tightness, i.e. you have some part of your measure escaping to infinity.

Comment: Oh that's great, I messed up that limit calculation. I now see how it violates tightness.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the lower bound from the Paley-Zygmund inequality allows us to show that the limit distribution is not tight, and so is not actually a probability measure.

Evaluating the terms in the expression:

$$\mathbb P[Y_n\ge\theta d]\ge (1-\theta)^2\frac{d^2}{2d + d^2} \rightarrow 1/2$$

and so the limit distribution of $Y_n$ is not tight and so does not exist.